# Is it possible to use SingleLiveEvent with Room in Android?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I was tinkering with [`SingleLiveEvent`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java). Is it possible to use it with Room database? I tried using it and got a build error saying `Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`. Are there any workarounds here? I have got an edge case where I would like to use it!

Answer (score 0):

`SingleLiveEvent` is `MutableLiveData` which is `LiveData`. You can return `List<LiveData<YourData>>` from Room with select query which is invoked in worker thread. No need to work with cursors in Room. get `List<LiveData<YourData>>` and on observe method send `List<YourData>` to required class or `RecyclerView`. What is your edge case for needing cursor?

> Caution: It's highly discouraged to work with the Cursor API because
>   it doesn't guarantee whether the rows exist or what values the rows
>   contain. Use this functionality only if you already have code that
>   expects a cursor and that you can't refactor easily.

However, you can get it with

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE age > :minAge LIMIT 5")
    public Cursor loadRawUsersOlderThan(int minAge);
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data)

Comment: On a high-level, my edge case is something like when an activity starts I want to check if a particular data exists is database if not show a fragment for adding that data. If that data exists I want to show an entirely different fragment which helps perform operations on this data. So if I add an observer for this data in the activity, it is triggered multiple times. I just want it to be triggered once.

Comment: Also I don't need to use a cursor. When I use `SingleLiveEvent` as return type in `Dao` it results in the error I mentioned.

Comment: Can you share your Entity class? You are not trying to put LiveData class to Room, right? You should wrap your data class with LiveData to update it.

Comment: No no. The `LiveData` part works fine. But observing on `LiveData` causes the code to execute each time the data changes in the fragment. I only want it to be triggered once. A workaround I am using now is to post value to `SingleLiveEvent` once it is loaded from Room using an `Executor` (Without wrapping using `LiveData` inside `Dao`)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Valgaal No. I went with using executor query `Room` & to post to the `SingleLiveData` instance inside my `Repository`